# pandas set_table_styles not working for table tag

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, css-selectors

I am using the following code to set a border to table and and some formatting to the header column. The styling for the header column works fine but the code doesn't render the border for the table.

```
styled_df = df.style.applymap(colorize).set_table_styles([
        {'selector': 'table',
         'props': 'border: 1; border-collapse: collapse; font-size: 13px;'
         },
        {'selector': 'thead',
         'props': 'background-color : #3176B5; color: white; padding: 4px;'
         }
    ])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily resolved by moving the table style into a `.set_table_attributes()` method, and being sure to specify the full border details.

Full implementation, and some demonstrative surrounding code:

```py
# Dummy Data
data = {
    'Name': ['John', 'Linda', 'Bob', 'Emily'],
    'Age': [25, 30, 22, 28],
    'Salary': [50000, 60000, 45000, 70000]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Dummy colorize function
def colorize(value):
    try:
        color = 'green' if value > 50000 else 'red'
        return f'color: {color}'
    except:  # in case of string
        return 'color: blue'

# Apply styling
styled_df = df.style.applymap(colorize).set_table_styles([
    {'selector': 'thead',
     'props': 'background-color: #3176B5; color: white; padding: 4px;'
     }
]).set_table_attributes('style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid black;; font-size: 13px;"')
```

Result:

[image: Table with styling]

Comment: Is there a way I can also set column borders?

Comment: Absolutely! Adding `{'selector': 'td', 'props': 'border-left: 1px solid black;'}` to the list within `.set_table_styles()` will add lines between the data. If you also want to add lines in the headers this can be done using the `'th'` selector as well.

Answer (score 2):

You may find it *counter-intuitive* but you can't apply an outer border with the `table` selector.

One of the solutions would be to use `""` (*aka, no selector*) and add the color/style of the border :

```
df.style.applymap(colorize).set_table_styles( # or `.map` if >= 2.1.0
    [
        {
            'selector': '', # << 1st fix
            'props': 'border: 1px solid black;' # << 2nd fix
            'border-collapse: collapse; font-size: 13px;'
         },
        {
            'selector': 'thead',
            'props': 'background-color : #3176B5; color: white; padding: 4px;'
        }
    ]
)
```

Output :

[image]

Used input :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from string ascii_uppercase

np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.rand(10, 10), columns=[*ascii_uppercase[:10]]
)

def colorize(v):
    return "background-color: orange" if v>.9 else ""
```

Comment: is there a way I can add borders to the column as well

Comment: For an outer border, just add `'border: 3px solid black;'` to the props of the `thead` selector. And if you need a border for each column separately, change the selector to `thead th`.